# How to delete .svn folders in my Source tree?

Tags: svn

I have checked out a source from my svn into my Linux PC. In every sub-folder there is a .svn folder.Now i want to know how can i delete that folder(.svn) everywhere in my tree?

Comment: Using what technology? What platform? Are you using Windows/Linux/OSX? Your question is too vague to be answered right now.

Comment: Note that these `.svn` directories are necessary if you still want to use any SubVersion features as these directories carry essential meta-information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using Unix platform, and can use bash.

```
find . -name ".svn" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: See this question for a solution that also handles embedded blanks in the pathnames.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861542/delete-all-svn-folders-in-paths-with-embedded-blanks

Answer (score 2):

find . -type d -name '.svn' -exec rm -Rf {} \;

Answer (score 2):

You can remove those directories manually but I suggest you just `svn export`:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

Answer (score 0):

[svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re10.html) will make a copy of you project with all the .svn folders removed

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove the `.svn` directories? I assume that you already know that they are used for storing svn information and should not be removed when svn is used on the local repository. If what you want is a clean copy of your repository excluding all the `.svn` directories use `svn export`: [svn export documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html).

Comment: i want to take the source to my Windows PC and use it with Source Insight.

Comment: Couldn't you just checkout your project using an svn client on Windows?

Comment: Because I inherited (read purchased) projects with the author's .svn info in them.  Different company, different subversion, etc. etc.