# Delete all .SVN folders in paths with embedded blanks

Tags: linux, bash, svn

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935776/how-to-delete-svn-folders-in-my-source-tree/13850323#13850323), and a hundred other places, there are mostly identical Linux solutions for deleting all .svn directories. It works beautifully until the paths happen to include blanks.  So, is there a technique to recursively remove .svn files in directories that contain blanks?  Perhaps a way to tell **find** to wrap its answers in quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can tell `find` to use null as an output delimiter instead of newline with the `-print0` action.

then you can tell `xargs` to use null as an input delimiter with the `-0` argument.

example:

```
find . -name '*.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} rm \'{}\'
```

the `-I{}` argument to xargs tells it to replace `{}` with the current line from standard input.  and personally, i like to include the backslash escaped quotes around the filenames as well, just to be doubly sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.svn' | while read x; do rm -r "$x" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wrapping in quotes seems to do the trick.

```
mkdir "x y"
mkdir x\ y/.svn
find . -name '.svn' | awk '{print "rm -rf \""$0"\""}' | bash
```

And finally:

```
ls x\ y
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 6 dylan dylan 4096 Dec 13 06:09 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 dylan dylan 4096 Dec 13 06:11 .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -name '.svn' -delete
```

Current versions of [GNU find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files) have gained the "-delete" action.

Comment: Yes, it does. In my code example I showed this by "-type d", which means directories.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a clean copy of your repository, have you envisaged the use of the [SVN `export` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)?

You will then get a copy of all the directories present in your repository, including the ones with spaces in their name, but without any `.svn` folder.

Comment: My project was purchased from another company.  HIs .svn directories were for a different server.